# How could I convert an []interface{} into a []string in Go?

Tags: string, go

I'm currently working with a bit of code at the moment, that involves a var with type `[]interface{}`

It has values within it, that I could easily access like so:

```
//given that args is of type []interface{}
name := args[0]
age  := args[1] //ect...
```

This is fine, but I'd like to be able to use the `strings` `Join` function, and it would typically error due to it requiring type `[]string` and not type `[]interface{}`.

What would be the most appropriate solution to be able to use the `Join` function, I'd guess maybe some sort on conversion?

Comment: Make this document your friend :) http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interface_conversions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to construct a new array of type `[]string` in order to use `strings.Join`:

```
import "fmt"
import "strings"

func main() {
    s1 := []interface{}{"a", "b", "c"}
    s2 := make([]string, len(s1))
    for i, s := range s1 {
        s2[i] = s.(string)
    }
    fmt.Println(strings.Join(s2, ", "))
}
```

See the related Golang FAQ entry: [can I convert a []T to an []interface{}?](http://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface)

Comment: I'd like to add that there's a small speed disadvantage by using `interface{}` instead of a specific type, the disadvantage gets almost 7x slower if you're not using any goroutines, shameless plug to some tests I ran : http://www.limitlessfx.com/golang-using-interface-vs-specific-type.html